# Send email and update field via Apex

Tags: apex, dml, singleemailmessage

I have apex class which is sending email and it works perfect, but together with email I want to change Case status and update a custom field.
Inside for loop it works, but I don't want to exceed governor limits. Can you please take a look?

PS. If-else statement with ContactEmail is only example, because I will change that in different DEV environment

```apex
public class EmailClass
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail() {
    List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    cases = [Select Id,ContactEmail, ContactId From Case Where Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c=6 AND ContactEmail!=null AND status='New' AND ContactId IN : contacts];
    OrgWideEmailAddress owea = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
    owea = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='myCompany'];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (Case cs : cases)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        // set properties on singular email
        List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        toAddress.add(cs.ContactEmail);
        email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        email.setReplyTo('customemail@example.pl');
        email.setWhatId(cs.Id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.id);
        List<String> ccAddress = new List<String>();
        email.setCcAddresses(ccAddress);
        //email.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
        cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Status = 'In Progress'
        if (cs.ContactEmail=='myemail@gmail.com')
        {
            email.setTemplateId('00X5t000000UJX5EAO');
        }
        else
        {
            email.setTemplateId('00X5t000000IA6jEAG');
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email }); 
        update cs;
```

Comment: Add each email to a list `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emails` and send emails in one go after the loop. Equivalently, `update cases` after the loop instead of updating each case individually inside.

Answer (score 1):

As you already created `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails` list in your code ,
You need to **add each email** to this **list** and send the emails **after the loop**.
As well you should update the `cases` list **after the loop**.

So the updated code will look like this :

```
public class EmailClass {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail() {
        // be careful with this query as you can have more than 50 000 Contacts where Email!=null 
        List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
        cases = [Select Id,ContactEmail, ContactId From Case Where Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c=6 AND ContactEmail!=null AND status='New' AND ContactId IN : contacts];
        OrgWideEmailAddress owea = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
        owea = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='myCompany' LIMIT 1];
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Case cs : cases)  {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            // set properties on singular email
            email.setToAddresses( new List<String>{ cs.ContactEmail } );
            email.setReplyTo('customemail@example.pl'); 
            email.setWhatId(cs.Id);
            email.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
            email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.id);
            email.setCcAddresses( new List<String>() );
            //email.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
            cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
            cs.Status = 'In Progress'
            if (cs.ContactEmail=='myemail@gmail.com') {
                email.setTemplateId('00X5t000000UJX5EAO');
            } else {
                email.setTemplateId('00X5t000000IA6jEAG');
            }
            emails.add( email ); // here we add the email to the list
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail( emails ); // here we send all emails 
        update cases; // here we update cases list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It works perfectly, now I can see how to add it to the list! :)

Comment: Great to hear. Please accept this answer as the one which resolved your issue and you could upvote it as well! :)